# How do i remove character in a column data using sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have table with data like

```
  samcol       
 60.78686
 46.0000 
 45.43240
 56.3453450
```

And i'm trying to remove '.' before decimal places. And table should looks like

```
  samcol

 6078686
 460000
 4543240 
 563453450
```

Comment: What is the field type?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Replace` String function to replace all the `.` with empty string

```
Select Replace(samcol,'.','') from yourtable
```

Comment: thanks but it ignores decimal places and diplays like '60', '46'  and not like full number with out '.'